# Python method to request attribute component that formed by list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I need to access an item from an attribute that formed in list. This is my code:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__words = []

    @property
    def word(self, index):
        return self.__words[index]

    @word.setter
    def word(self, word):
        self.__words.append(str(word))
```

When I tested it in terminal, its result is as follow:

```
import coba
a = coba.Foo()
a.word = 'ok'
a.word(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: word() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'
```

Why I cannot access list item using that method? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why not just expose the list itself in the property then use square brackets? I'm not sure you can have arguments with a `@property`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, Paul Rooney I t can be accessed by []. And at this moment I have known, when I use @property I cannot use argument for it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @PaulRooney: You definitely can't have a `property` getter that takes arguments (or a setter that takes more than one). Directly exposing `__words` without a `property` wrapper, or only giving it a getter that returns the internal `list`, and the caller performs indexing or appends on that is a much better idea. The proposed design here is just begging to be misunderstood/misused.

Comment: There is also a semantic ambiguity in the setter, since what you make look like assignment `a.word = 'ok'` is actually appending to the internal list. So if you did `a.word = 'not ok'` then its value would be `['ok', 'not ok']`. Not what one would expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot add arbitrary arguments to a method decorated by `@property`. So, if you really want to do this, you can return a method that takes an index instead of trying to get the value itself:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__words = []

    @property
    def word(self):
        return lambda index: self.__words[index]

    @word.setter
    def word(self, word):
        self.__words.append(str(word))
        print(self.__words)

a = Foo()
a.word = 'ok'
print(a.word(0))  # 'ok'
```

Note that this is generally not a very Pythonic class. Python takes a "trust the caller" approach, so it's rare to see read-only or restricted write implementations like this. As others have said, it's much more common to just use the internal list and trust the caller to not mess with it in unintended ways.